# Help in Objective C to make a webservice app

Tags: objective-c

I am using **Objective C GNU GCC compiler** on windows and want to make App which communicate with a **server (webserver) using webservice**, send and recieve request between **client and server**.
I know basics but not having any idea from should I start.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for recommendations of libraries to talk to a webservice? SOAP? ReST?

Comment: Actually I don't know about these! I Tell you in detail about my project from ground up.I simply want to access any Url either on Internet or Intranet and sending username and password to login submission. All I want to implement on GNU GCC compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing network requests with basic authentication, I would recommend using either Three20 (https://github.com/facebook/three20) or ASI Http (https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request).

There are plenty of examples around for using them, but they use the underlying Cocoa Foundation classes. I've never tried to use these on Windows before with the GNU Objective C compiler

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick answer I just check it and If needed I will come back to you.

Comment: I looked into those links but unable to get something from it as seem very complex,But from some blog I make a program that sipmly connect to a url and show its contents(may be XML source file) on GCC compiler prompt using a NSString string.Now can I use it to send username and password from this track.Please help still out of track.